# Facebook Webhook getting Manage_pages permission has been revoked for the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on creating a webhook app and when working will then  create an app integrating the FB API  to pass lead data to backend.

I finally got the Webhook setup and all the permissions

- pages_show_list
- leads_retrieval
- pages_read_engagement
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_read_user_content
- pages_manage_engagement

I subscribed to the client's page and all seems to be good now that I finally see my Webhook on the Lead Ads Testing Tool

However, when I submit a test I get the message "Manage_pages permission has been revoked for the app".  I'm not exactly sure why but I suspect need  review process?  Here are my questions

1. Do I need to go through App Review to solve this problem?
2. I created the webhook/app for a client and I have access to his Business manger account.  Do I still need to go through App review ?
3. If I do need to go through app review, one of the requirements is to do Business Verfication and the only option is to create a Business Manager account. But this isn't for me, its for my client.  Do I still need to create the Busines manager account?
4. This is going to be just a webhook for leadgen so no facebook login needed.  Is FB Login required for App reivew?
5. Anything else I'm missing to get "magage_pagess permissions"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes
4. You can find details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/) about which permission needs app review. ( just click on the permissions which will redirect to detail page , thats where you'll find whether it needs app review or not )
5. Nope, Process is simple. you need to add verified business account / individual verification in order to use your app in live.

Comment: Thanks fahim152!   One issue I'm running into is App Review(AR). My client added me to his FB Business Account with "Employee access". I was hoping I could submit AR under his business acct but the App is under my dev acct (my fb acct) and I couldn't figure how to submit AR using his Bus. Acct.
I then created a Bus Acct but FB is asking for business docs I don't have :-(.  How can I submit the AR under his Bus. Acct without having him do anything since I'm the developer? Thanks again!

Comment: Make him administrator of that app and tell him to add his verified business account with the app.

Comment: Oh my,I've been trying to figure this out for ever.  I'll give this a try.  Thanks!!!

Comment: you are welcome brother. let me know if you need any more help. I've been working with facebook APIs for more than a  year now. I think I learned a very little till now :3

Comment: Hi fahim152. So finally got the app approved & as you suggested made the business owner admin for the app. We got his Business Verification approved.But now when I either try to use Testing Tool "create lead" I still get "Manage_pages permission has been revoked for the app" or I use Graph API explorer & use say /leadgen_forms get " Requires pages_manage_ads permission to manage the object, the app may have the permission but in order to use this API, the app needs to be owned by a verified business".The goal is to use webhook to retrieve leads & I have all need permissions.Any suggestions?

Comment: did you add your ( your client's ) business verified profile with the app you created ? Please check from Setting -> Basic  and also check your current approved permission list from left menu App Review -> My permissions and feature. I think your app still needs to be submitted for those permissions. for every usage you need to submit application  to fb app review team. check those permissions from App Review -> Permissions or Features

Comment: "did you add your ( your client's ) business verified profile with the app you created" yes.  The strange thing is I requested 1. pages_read_engagement, 2 pages_manage_meta, 3. pages_manage_ads, 4. leads_retrieval 5. ads_management.  Only #5 shows Live and the rest show "Complete verification".  Under "Additional Requirements" they all require the same "Business or Individual Verfication" and "Contract Signing".  If i click "View" on any item takes me to "My permissions" which only lists #5 the Live one.  Not sure what next to do. Wish FB had a support area for this.

Comment: when you are requesting for those permission you have to clearly mention whats your intention to use those feature in your application ( web / mobile whatever ..) you gotta show them your developed product and its use cases by screen recording. Check this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review#supplemental-terms 

you can find a video in this page. Watch and listen to that carefully.

Comment: turns out more complicated than that.  Time and patience :-).  On Sat only the one permission available of the 5 I requested.  Yesterday all were available!   I suspect with current situation someone at FB manually is enabling these and just had to wait for the other 4 to become available.  This is so cool!  Now able to see response of webhook and use the associated APIs!  Thanks so much again for your help!

Comment: You are welcome brother. :)  dont forget to mark as answer if you think my answer is correct for your issue.